# Which dictionaries contain sample sentences with a word we searched?

Tags: word-usage, dictionary

I am using [dict.cc](http://dict.cc) und [PONS](http://en.pons.com)  for searching word meaning.
But it doesn't have sample sentence mentioned in it. 
Which dictionary is good for getting sentences as well.

Comment: http://de.thefreedictionary.com/

Comment: Pons provides examples from the Internet; though they're not verified by editors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.dwds.de/ is a monolingual dictionary, it is the best I've ever seen on the web, it also contains etymology and - as you requeste - example sentences.

[de.wiktionary.org](http://de.wiktionary.org) also has example sentences and etymology.

And of course there is http://www.duden.de/ which also has example sentences and (rather few) etymological information.